# Problem with my makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I think I have a problem with my makefile. I'm writing this program:

- `Q2.cpp` contains the main.
- `Agent.cpp` `Agent.h`
- `Timing.cpp` `Timing.h`
- `RandomDouble.cpp` `RandomDouble.cpp`

And I'm using the header `randoma.h` in `RandomDouble.cpp`.
I downloaded the `randomaelf64.a` file and I wrote this makefile:

```
 Q2 : Q2.o Agent.o Timing.o RandomDouble.o
     g++ -Wall -g randomaelf64.a RandomDouble.o Q2.o Agent.o Timing.o -o Q2

 Q2.o : Q2.cpp Agent.h Timing.h
     g++ -Wall -g -c Q2.cpp -o Q2.o

 Agent.o : Agent.cpp Agent.h Timing.h RandomDouble.h PrintQ2.h
     g++ -Wall -g -c Agent.cpp -o Agent.o

 RandomDouble.o : RandomDouble.cpp RandomDouble.h  randoma.h
     g++ -Wall -g -c RandomDouble.cpp -o RandomDouble.o

 Timing.o : Timing.cpp Timing.h Agent.h
     g++ -Wall -g -c Timing.cpp -o Timing.o

 clear :
     rm *.o Q2
```

Except for the first command, each g++.. command is working when I do it separately.
Even when I add a `main()` to `RandomDouble.cpp` and run:

```
g++ -Wall -g randomael64.a RandomDouble.cpp -o rand
```

it's working. So I think that maybe the problem is with my makefile.

When I run `make` I get this error:

```
RandomDouble.o: In function `InitSeed()':
/cs/stud/ofrenk33/CPP/ex1/RandomDouble.cpp:11: undefined reference to `MersenneRandomInit'
RandomDouble.o: In function `InitSeed(int)':
/cs/stud/ofrenk33/CPP/ex1/RandomDouble.cpp:16: undefined reference to `MersenneRandomInit'
RandomDouble.o: In function `GetRandomDouble()':
/cs/stud/ofrenk33/CPP/ex1/RandomDouble.cpp:21: undefined reference to `MersenneRandom'
Agent.o: In function `Agent::SendMessage()':
/cs/stud/ofrenk33/CPP/ex1/Agent.cpp:31: undefined reference to
...
make: *** [Q2] Error 1
```

I need to say that there are functions declared in `randoma.h` which are in the `randomaelf64.a` library.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: So what exactly is _not_ working for you? Are you getting an error message? If not, what are the symptoms of your problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to link against the library *after* all your own object files. The linker will only include as much of the library as it needs, and if there are no unresolved references yet, then none of the library will be needed. Change the first rule to:

```
Q2 : Q2.o Agent.o Timing.o RandomDouble.o 
    g++ -Wall -g RandomDouble.o Q2.o Agent.o Timing.o randomaelf64.a -o Q2
```